# Tomcat: 403 The server understood the request but refuses to authorize it error after keycloak login

Tags: tomcat, keycloak

I'm currently trying to configure a Tomcat 8 web application to use Keycloak as it's identity provider. I followed the instructions on the [official keycloak documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_tomcat_adapter) and also added the user roles 'user' to my Keycloak Realm that the user should have to get access to the web-app.
In the web.xml i also added this role to the auth-constraint.
Here's my web.xml

```
 <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Customers</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>this is ignored currently</realm-name>
</login-config>

<security-role>
    <role-name>user</role-name>
</security-role>
```

When i try to access a path (/*) tomcat successfully redirects me to the keycloak login page.
But after logging in with an user that has the user role assigned, i only get the following error in my browser:

```
HTTP Status 403 – Forbidden - The server understood the request but refuses to authorize it
```

I'm expecting to be successfully redirected as the logged in user has the role that is given in the web.xml.

Comment: Instead of answering in a comment, could you write an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed it by myself. If anyone else has this problem, in my keycloak.json file "use-resource-role-mappings" was set to true. After setting it to false everything worked.